# What is the meaning of "<movie-title>" with "<actor-or-actress>"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases, ambiguity

My husband wrote another question on here, and he wrote:

> I was watching the movie 'The Fugitive' with Harrison Ford.

I told him:

> That means that I am sitting beside Harrison Ford watching the movie.

So what does the phrase mean in this context in the USA?

Comment: In this context, "with" means "starring" or "featuring".

Comment: It's a perfectly natural expression to say who is starring in a movie. So nothing to change there. It *could* also mean that Harrison Ford was watching the movie alongside your husband, but what are the odds of that?

Comment: Never assume a little word like _with_ or _to_ only has one possible meaning. It doesn't. [Not even close](https://www.wordnik.com/words/with).

Comment: *I was watching the movie 'The Fugitive' with Harrison Ford* is a genuine example of ambiguity, in my humble opinion. For example, ["I saw Jane Austen using binoculars."](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs262/unit-3#quiz-ambiguity) has two possible readings. Your sentence reminds me of a funny interpretation of *[They ate the pizza with anchovies](http://imgur.com/z2hzXAp)*. :-) By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: For true ambiguity… "I am watching the movie 'The Fugitive' with my husband", said Calista.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is called **PP attachment ambiguity**.  You have a preposition phrase (PP), *with Harrison Ford*, and you have to figure out what part of the sentence it attaches to.

1. Does it attach high, to *watching*?  If so, Harrison Ford is watching the movie with you, like this:

   > I'm watching with Harrison Ford.
2. Does it attach low, to *the movie 'The Fugitive'*?  If so, you're telling the listener that Harrison Ford is in the movie, like this:

   > It's a movie with Harrison Ford.

When you have this sort of ambiguity, you have to figure out what makes sense from context.  Both of these are possible, but the latter is probably more likely.

If you think the ambiguity might lead to misunderstanding, you can always rephrase:

> I'm watching *The Fugitive*.  Harrison Ford is in it.

But native speakers use ambiguous sentences all the time; if they fail to communicate, they just go back and explain what they meant.  You can do the same thing, if you like.

Comment: Or, I am watching Harrison Ford's The Fugitive (InE).